# Post request with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, swagger, postman

I want to test my Web API with a postman on the javascript app.

I have the following swagger.

```js
"/attachment/erase": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Erase ",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "folder",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "folder('s) detail",
            "required": true
          },
          {
            "name": "type",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "ABC or BCD",
            "required": true
          },
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": ["files"],
              "properties": {
                "attachments": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "description": "The file(s) to delete"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "file(s) erased."
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So I send the following request :

[image: postman parameters]

with the following body :

[image: request body]

In return, I get an error 415.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` when the API is expecting `application/json`.

Comment: ups, beginner mistake. 
Thank you, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a form-data parameter file, please refer the image[image: Postman body form-data param]